# How to cache responses with RESTlets?

Tags: caching, restlet

I have read about the CacheDirective class in RESTlets for caching responses, however I have not seen any examples of how to implement it.

Does anyone have an example of how I can accomplish this in my ServerResource class?

Comment: Is the client for your requests a browser ?

Comment: No, they are an Android and iOS app.  Does that change the configuration on the RESTlet side?

Comment: Restlet doesn't have its own caching service yet. However, if your Restlet client uses the org.restlet.ext.net.jar extension for the HTTP client connector, then it will benefit from Android's native caching features.

Comment: Does the Cache Directive class not accomplish this?

Comment: @Atma idem for browser cache - i sent responses with ETag and the browser resends the ETAG from disk cache upon re-request, then my server answers 304-not modified in 95% of the requests.